# Separate EDMX for grouping stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

I have a complex database and would like to know if creating a separate edmx for stored procedures is a good route to take? My idea is to have multiple edmx files, based on the applications using the database. That way each application would have access only to the stored procedures it needed.

Comment: Do your procedures map to entities?

Comment: Well no and yes. The procedures are Select and a separate custom mapping exist depending on the need. However the procedure may even be changebase on the customer

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why this would be a problem.

While @Khan might be right on some scenario, I believe if you project is large enough then you can, seperate them if it helps you stay organized.

I have done this in some of my application where I wanted to separate the concerns.

My solution had a admin project and a user project, I added a third one as a DLL which contained  two EDMX.
Then I added a reference to the same dll on both project.

It just did not seem right for me to mix both Data Access Layer.

Something like this for admin:

```
private void SomeAdminFunction()
{
    using (var db = new AdminEntities())
    {
      //Access all Admin Stored Procedures
    }
}
```

for users:

```
private void SomeUserFunction()
{
    using (var db = new UserEntities())
    {
          //Access all User Stored Procedures
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking whether having a separate EDM just for stored procedures is a good idea.  Not whether it is a good idea to use EF for Stored Procedures or not.

Answer (score 1):

The following reasons NOT to separate `EMD`s come to mind

1. If your procedures map to entities which you will be writing back to a database, you would be creating more work for yourself.
2. Having 2 `EDM`s means having 2 choices of `Context` for what may not have a logical separation.
3. Having 2 `EDM`s does not seem to appear cleaner in any way that I can think of.

Comment: My frustration is that the application will be use for different customer and each customer may and will have some logic different.
But the goal is to reduce the complexity going forward for maintenance and enhancement.
My problem is that i have never seen anyone separating Store procedure to table in EF. Should i be the first one?